# Privacy Policy for the app on Google Play that doesn't collect any user data

Tags: google-play, policy, privacy

I want to publish a simple app that doesn't collect any personal data. It is an offline game (noughts and crosses), that doesn't require any account, and stores only field state on the user's device. I don't have any server and don't transfer the data anywhere, so it's fully offline. But Google Play asks for a Privacy Policy. How can I get it? Is there any standard Privacy Policy for such type of application? Can I just write something like "We don't store and transfer any personal data"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest way is just to use a privacy policy generator such as this one: https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/

It's simple to use and only takes a few minutes to get you a privacy policy

Answer (score 12):

Disclaimer: [I Am Not A Lawyer](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=%22ianal%22)

I recently ran into this myself. I have a very simple app that does not collect any personal information.

I looked all over and tried a few of the privacy policy generators, but they all seemed like overkill. So I started with a simple statement:

> This application does not collect or store personal data.

Then based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964012/privacy-policy-for-apps-that-do-not-collect-datas#comment110812472_49964482), I added another note:

> If you installed this application from Google Play, then Google Play does collect some personal data. Please see the privacy policy for Google Play Services here: https://policies.google.com/privacy

Here's the whole thing: https://github.com/bmaupin/android-pitchpipe/blob/main/metadata/en-US/privacy_policy.txt